# 3 random numbers between 1 and 20. Compare first number to second and third

Tags: javascript, html, random, generator

I have to make a program that generates 3 random numbers between 1 and 20 and the first number needs to be compared against the other two when a button is clicked. The output should display all 3 of the numbers and indicate the result of the comparison, for example: 1) The first number is less than both the second and third numbers; 2) The first number is between the other two numbers; 3) The first number is greater than the other two; 4) The first number is equal to one of the other two numbers; or 5) All three numbers are equal.

I'm generally new to programming so any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: First try something and post your attempt, then ask for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function compare() {
                var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
                var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
                var c = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
                var message = "1st - "+a+"; 2st - "+b+"; 3st - "+c+"\n";
                if (a < b && a < c) {
                    message += 'The first number is less than both the second and third numbers';
                } else if ((a < b && a > c) || (a < c && a > b)) {
                    message += 'The first number is between the other two numbers';
                } else if (a > b && a > c) {
                    message += 'The first number is greater than the other two';
                } else if (a == b && b == c) {
                    message += 'All three numbers are equal';
                } else {
                    message += "The first number is equal to one of the other two numbers"
                }
                alert(message);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onClick="compare();">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me out a lot

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` will return a number between 0 and 1 (with decimal).
For a specific number range you can do:

```
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * y) + z);
```

Where `y` is the <strike>Max</strike> (max - min + 1) and `z` is the Min. For your example you would do:

```
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
```

As for the comparison, because there are so many scenarios you should use `if-else` statements so it would look like:

```
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
var z = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
var output = null;
if(x > y && x > z){
  output = 'The first number is greater than the other two';
}else if(x < y && x < z){
  output = 'The first number is less than the other two';
}
```

And so on...

Comment: ok thank you. Ill give this a try

Comment: The `y` in the random expression is not the max, it's the range (max - min + 1). If you for example want a random number between 10 and 20, the range is 11, so you use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 10`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 20.</p>

<button onclick="x()">Roll</button>
<button onclick="y()">Roll</button>
<button onclick="z()">Roll</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
var z = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
var output = null;
if(x > y && x > z){
  output = 'The first number is greater than the other two';
}else if(x < y && x < z){
  output = 'The first number is less than the other two';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```